# angular 3 nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, filter

Can someone help me regarding my code I already search but had no luck on logic.

i am trying to get a nested drop but i get the same result on 3-child hierarchy.

this is the data from my API.

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "Metro Manila",
      "parent": null
    },
    {
      "id": "101",
      "name": "Manila",
      "parent": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "10101",
      "name": "Malate",
      "parent": "101"
    },
    {
      "id": "10102",
      "name": "Ermita",
      "parent": "101"
    },
    {
      "id": "10103",
      "name": "Binondo",
      "parent": "101"
    },
    {
      "id": "102",
      "name": "Makati",
      "parent": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "10201",
      "name": "Poblacion",
      "parent": "102"
    },
    {
      "id": "10202",
      "name": "Bel-Air",
      "parent": "102"
    },
    {
      "id": "10203",
      "name": "San Lorenzo",
      "parent": "102"
    },
    {
      "id": "10204",
      "name": "Urdaneta",
      "parent": "102"
    },
    {
      "id": "103",
      "name": "Marikina",
      "parent": "1"
    },
    {
      "id": "10301",
      "name": "Sto Nino",
      "parent": "103"
    },
    {
      "id": "10302",
      "name": "Malanday",
      "parent": "103"
    },
    {
      "id": "10303",
      "name": "Concepcion I",
      "parent": "103"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "CALABARZON",
      "parent": null
    },
    {
      "id": "201",
      "name": "Laguna",
      "parent": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "20101",
      "name": "Calamba",
      "parent": "201"
    },
    {
      "id": "20102",
      "name": "Sta. Rosa",
      "parent": "201"
    },
    {
      "id": "202",
      "name": "Cavite",
      "parent": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "20201",
      "name": "Kawit",
      "parent": "202"
    },
    {
      "id": "203",
      "name": "Batangas",
      "parent": "2"
    },
    {
      "id": "20301",
      "name": "Lipa",
      "parent": "203"
    },
    {
      "id": "20302",
      "name": "Tanauan",
      "parent": "203"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "Central Luzon",
      "parent": null
    },
    {
      "id": "301",
      "name": "Bulacan",
      "parent": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "302",
      "name": "Nueva Ecija",
      "parent": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "303",
      "name": "Tarlac",
      "parent": "3"
    },
    {
      "id": "304",
      "name": "Pampanga",
      "parent": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

this.data = result.body.data;

```
    let parents = this.data.filter(x => x.parent == null);
    let child_id = [];
    let child_id2 = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < parents.length; i++) {
      let _myTreelist = new ParentData();
     _myTreelist.data.parent = parents[i].name;

     child_id = this.data.filter(x => x.parent == parents[i].id); //get child-1 with id
     _myTreelist.data.child.child1 = child_id.map((item) => {
                return item.name
              })
      for (let e = 0; e < child_id.length; e++) { //10 ids
      child_id2 = this.data.filter(a => a.parent === child_id[e].id); //get child-2 with id

     _myTreelist.data.child.child.child2 = child_id2.map((item) => {
        return item.name
      })
    
    }
     this.parentList.push(_myTreelist);
    }
```

this is the image output I get.

[image]

it works the first and 2nd nested but in the 3rd it display same

Comment: You should start a stackblitz, it would be a lot easier to help

Answer (score 0):

make a recursive function

```
  getChild(element:any,data:any[])
  {
      element.children=data.filter((x:any)=>x.parent==element.id)
      if (element.children.length)
        element.children.forEach((x:any)=>this.getChild(x,data))
      else
        element.children=null;
    return element
  }
```

then

```
treeData=this.data.filter(x=>!x.parent)
           .map(x=>this.getChild(x,this.data))
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-a5ekfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If you use an API and an observable use pipe map

```
treeData$=this.service.getData().pipe(
    map((data:any[])=>{
       return data.filter(x=>!x.parent).map(x=>this.getChild(x,data))
                                 
    })
 )
```

Comment: A recursive function can "sound" complex. Really you can see as: How get the children of one element? what happens if the element in children has children? You see that it's the same look for children in an element without parent than if has parent, so you get it!